# Is there a way to get string array from array of NSManagedObject for specific attributes

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, core-data

```
        var resultsOfFetch = [AnyObject]()
        if fetchRequest != nil && (textField.text!.characters.count > 4){
            do{
              let results = try privateMOC.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest!)
                if results.count > 0{
                    resultsOfFetch = results
                }
            }catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error: \(error) " +
                    "description \(error.description)")
            }
        }

        var itemNamesArray = [String]()
        switch textField{
        case self.stampNameField:
            for result in resultsOfFetch as! [Stamp]{
                itemNamesArray.append(result.itemName)
            }
```

I'm trying to save the itemName of all the returned fetch items in an `array`. Is there a better way to do this? I don't want to be iterating every item in the result array and then taking its item name and then adding it to the itemNamesArray, because it takes time and is very inefficient. Is there a faster way?

Comment: do you want to fetch only one attribute `itemName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` closure for that

```
itemNamesArray = (resultsOfFetch as! [Stamp]).map {$0.itemName}
```